# PDO prepared statement fetch() returning double results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch

I have a script that is outputting to a CSV file. However, even though there is currently one row in the database, the output I'm getting is echoing out each column from each row in the table twice.

For example:
1,1,John,John,Smith,Smith,2014,2014
Should be
1,John,Smith,2014

This worked fine before I went with PDO and prepared statements, so I'm thinking maybe I'm not understanding how fetch() works correctly.
Below is my code. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

```
// get rows
$query_get_rows = "SELECT * FROM Contacts ORDER BY date_added DESC";
$result_get_rows = $conn->prepare($query_get_rows);
$result_get_rows->execute();         
$num_get_rows = $result_get_rows->rowCount();

while ($rows_get_rows = $result_get_rows->fetch()) 
{
  $csv .= '"'.join('","', str_replace('"', '""', $rows_get_rows))."\"\n";
}
echo $csv;
exit;
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should say to PDO, that you want only an associative array or a numbered array:

```
while ($rows_get_rows = $result_get_rows->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

to get an associative array or

```
while ($rows_get_rows = $result_get_rows->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
```

to get an array indexed by the column number

from [PDOStatement::fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

> fetch_style
>
> Controls how the next row will be returned to the caller.
> This value must be one of the PDO::FETCH_* constants, defaulting to
> value of PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE (which defaults to
> PDO::FETCH_BOTH).
>
> PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: returns an array indexed by column name as returned
> in your result set
>
> **PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default)**: returns an array indexed by both column
> name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set

Comment: Thanks the explanation. I assumed all this time it worked by fetch_assoc only. var_dump shows exactly what you posted as well!